# How can I print something from a pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, char, printf, c-strings

I wrote this program to test something with pointer. The two words in the array will be swapped at the end.

int main() {

```
char * word2 [] = { "LAGER" , "GERALD" };

char * temp = NULL;

temp = word2[0];        

word2[0] = word2[1];    
word2[1] = temp;        

printf("%c \n" , *word2[1]);

return 0;
```

}

I now want to print the second word after they swapped but it only prints the first letter and not the whole word. How do I print the whole word?

Comment: Write  printf("%s\n" ,word2[1]);

Comment: Now it works, thank you. But why do I have to wirte word2 without the star? Why does it not work with the star?

Comment: The expression word2[1] has the type char *. So dereferencing the pointer you will get a single object of the type char. But you need to output the whole string pointed to by the pointer instead of a single character.

Answer (score 2):

This call of printf

```
printf("%c \n" , *word2[1]);
```

outputs the first character of the second element of the array that stores pointers to string literals.

That is as the expression `word2[1]` has the type `char *` due to the declaration of the array then the expression  `*word2[1]` has the type `char` and the function `printf` using the conversion specifier `%c` outputs the character..

Instead write

```
printf("%s\n" , word2[1])
```